# match a label with particular class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have following structure:

```
 <label></label><input type="text" id="t1" /><label class="a">fsafs<label>
```

Now I want a jquery which can match only those labels with class "a" and it should be after id "t1"

I also want clear content of that label

Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For selecting only one `label.a` that comes immediately after `#t1`, use [`+`](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector):

```
$('#t1 + label.a').text('');
```

For all sibling `label.a` elements that come after `#t1` (i.e. on the same level), use [`~`](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector):

```
$('#t1 ~ label.a').text('');
```

Comment: @I-M-JM: Of course it works. http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/wje3V Or, you're not giving us the correct structure.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Good call, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#t1').nextAll('label.a').html('');
})
```